# Implementing Chiptune SFX's in FMOD

Tags: fmod, chipsound

Just checking to see if anyone has some tricks to implementing chiptune style sfx's in FMOD up their sleeves?

Cheers!

Eric

Comment: Like generating them at runtime?

Comment: yeah is that possible? 

Comment: What's the target engine?

Answer (score 1):

Hey Eric!

I answered your #gameaudio tweet with a link to [Stephan Schutze](http://www.stephanschutze.com/fmod-101.html). But if I understand you correctly after Miles B question then you don't want to implement pre-made 8-bit sfx, you wonder if FMOD can create them for you?

Comment: Well I had planned on implementing pre-made 8-bit sfx's but I was wondering if there are any tricks, like FMOD generating the sounds, that I could utilize. 

Comment: Hmmm, as far as I know FMOD can not really generate audio itself. It's been a couple of years since I worked with it though so perhaps there's been some changes.

Comment: Actually, FMod can generate 6 basic oscillator sounds. You can utilize them for Chiptune, maybe? 

Comment: @Kabraxis Interesting. Didn't know about those. Although, I wonder if there's a way to stich them together and utilize them in a subtractive synthesizer way? Quite certainly they can't be utilized for FM though?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not exactly a trick, but it could be useful: If you create pregenerated segments of a chiptune, you could use FMOD's interactive music system to stitch them together in different ways at run-time based on in-game events. You could even do this down to the note-by-note level, but I suspect that that would be much more labour than it would be worth.

Alternatively, you could concievably generate your chiptunes programatically as part of your game and feed them to FMOD as programmer sounds, but that would require some very strong programmer-fu.